# Custom Exception Handling on Select Query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'v been looking around, and not able to find anything helpful in my specific situation. I'm attempting to debug a query that I have limited access to. I cannot access the database itself, but I can query the database.

The query is something along the lines of

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE col1 = TRUNC(:varibleName)
```

I am fairly sure the :variableName is being sent as a date+time, and col1 is a date column. However, I get the error, "Expected Date, got Number".

What I would like to do is see what the value of :variableName is when being run in this query. I have been attempting to find out by using custom exception handling but it doesn't seem like I can run a simple query.

Is there any way I can see the value of the variable when it causes an error?

Comment: Have you tried something like this:   TO_DATE(variableName, 'M/DD/YYYY')

Comment: Yes, it gives a variety of errors - usually things like the string being too long compared to the format, or incorrect formatting issues. This is the reason I need to know what exactly its looking at to be able to format it properly.

Comment: I don't know if this is syntactically correct, but maybe this?

SELECT varibleName as 'myCol', col1, col2, col3 FROM table

Answer (score 1):

You may use `TO_DATE` and pass variable in a particular format.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
     FROM table WHERE col1 = TRUNC(:to_date(:varibleName,'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

Now, you can pass a string like `2019-09-01` , `2019-07-20` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add-on to Kaushik,

**Query:**

To replicate the error:
Error:ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

```
with cte as (select trunc(sysdate) as dt, sysdate-1  as yst_dt from dual)
select * from cte where dt=TRUNC(2019-07-18) ;
```

By using To_Date format:

```
with cte as (select trunc(sysdate) as dt, sysdate-1  as yst_dt from dual)
select * from cte where dt=TRUNC(to_date('2019-07-18','yyyy-mm-dd')) ;
```